# Click through a DIV (Canvas) to underlying elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a JavaScript that runs a particle effect the covers the whole screen. The problem with this is that I can't click on any elements that lay under that particle effect now. I have played around with z-index and pointer-events: none but nothings seems to be working for me. Any brilliant ideas on how to get around this? See link below.

https://developer.my-callboard.com/tandem

Comment: `.tandem-name-container{ z-index: 10; }` (replace the rule that says `6!important`)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the class `particle-container` to have `z-index: 0 !important`